# Correlating multiple dynamic values

Tags: correlation, loadrunner, vugen

How can I get the value of important id and ValueType?

I have tried using web_save_param_regexp (but unfortunately I don't fully understand how the function works).

I have also tried using web_save_param (with the help of offset and length).
unfortunately once again I cannot get the accurate value some values change in length specially when the total amount values dynamically changes per run.

```
<important id=\"insertsomevalueshere\" record=\"1\" nucTotal=\"NUC609.40\"><total amount=\"68.75\" currency=\"USD\"/><total amount=\"609.40\" currency=\"USD\"/><out avgsomecost=\"540.65\" ValueType=\"insertsomevalueshere\" containsawesomeness=\"1\" Score=\"-97961\" somedatatype=\"1\" typeofData=\"VAL\" web=\"1\">
```

Comment: Training on the tool?  Mentor on site with you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put these lines of code *before* the line of code which does your web request:

```
web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=importantid","Regexp=<important id=\\\"(.*?)\\\"",LAST);
web_reg_save_param_regexp("ParamName=ValueType","Regexp= ValueType=\\\"(.*?)\\\"",LAST);
```

You will then have two stored parameters 'importantid' and 'ValueType'

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic number of elements to correlate?  Your path for resubmission is through web_custom_request().   You will need to build the string you need dynamically with the name:value pairs for all of the data which needs to be included.

This path will place a premium on your string manipulation skills in the language of the tool.  The default path is through C, but you have other language options if your skills are more refined in another language.